# Bin packing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, bin-packing

I have a kitchen heating meals from frozen, they need to produce meals to a head count order.  The meals come in frozen sizes of portions such as 4's, 6's etc.  The larger sizes have a lower cost per unit.  So allowing waste, how do I calculate the sizes to complete an order at the lowest cost.

Comment: Seems like the answer is in your title..

Comment: Your question is so generic that you can only take one of the bin packing algorithms available for your language of choice and input your parameters. Where are you stuck?

Comment: No answer Andrew? I'll accept the first helpful response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem kind of sounds like the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) to me. I'm assuming that a [greedy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) will not work here because there appear to be overlapping subproblems. You will probably have to use a [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) algorithm which determines the minimum cost for a given head count by calculating the cost for all possible combinations of meal portions satisfying that head count.

I only pointed you in the right direction because this sounds like it might be homework. Either way this problem sounds like it can be reduced to one with a well-known solution.

Comment: OK I will implement knapsack to further my understanding of dynamic programming, and then see if I can modify it.. Many thanks.  Not homework, these are real hospitals with real money to save. :)

Comment: @Neil If you're working in Java and you want to save as much as possible (and go beyond the greedy algorithms), take a look at reusing open source libs, like in [this tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#cloudBalancingTutorial).

Comment: I believe this is variable sized bin packing problem. VSBPP

Comment: Update: we can solve this VSBPP with the excel solver plugin. Next step would be to use something like MS Solver foundation to solve the problem with C#.